# EnsureUser - User not found using PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, user-profile

I'm using Power Shell script to get user.

I have include the Domain name in EnsureUser - **Domain\Username**

Please check below code.

```
$AuthorLoginName = "domain\akshay"
try{
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUser]$Author = $w.EnsureUser($AuthorLoginName)  }
catch
{}
```

Please suggest some workaround

Comment: tried `i:0#.w|domain\akshay` ?

Comment: Are you using claims?

Comment: @GautamSheth let me try!

Comment: cool ! will be adding it as answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `i:0#.w|domain\akshay` as input.

So try below code:

```
$AuthorLoginName = "i:0#.w|domain\akshay"
try{
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUser]$Author = $w.EnsureUser($AuthorLoginName)  }
catch
{}
```